# How to ascertain actual location of duplicately named UNLOCODE region when co-ordinates are not provided

Tags: coordinates, internationalization, standards

As https://www.reddit.com/u/rokejulianlockhart/s/9Gp5N5Htva explains, I ask this to remediate a problem:

> Which of `GBR`'s `HAO` or `HWX` refers to https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hanworth,+Norwich/@52.8725787,1.2563244,15z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x47d75cae1237c9a1:0xafeb0d2650b60ec6!8m2!3d52.8724959!4d1.2581449!16s%2Fg%2F1jkyh3phj?entry=ttu :
>
> 1. I don't know what format the co-ordinates provided for `HAO` are; and
> 2. `HWX` doesn't even *have* co-ordinates listed.
>
> Additionally, I see no way to request clarification, even from https://apps.unece.org/unlocode/manage.aspx .

Consequently, it appears to me as if the public registers available from UNECE don't mandate that every attribute of every entry be filled, yet don't provide any way to request clarification.

Summarily, does a method which I could use to ascertain the location of a duplicately named entry without a location exist?

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about its compilation is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo, would you consider https://service.unece.org/trade/locode/gb.htm to be open data?

Comment: I’m no arbiter of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the table https://service.unece.org/trade/locode/gb.htm have a look at the column `SubDiv`. If you look at the description of the column at https://service.unece.org/trade/locode/Service/LocodeColumn.htm#Subdivision, you can read:

> Column "Subdivision" is intended to contain the ISO 1-3 character
> alphabetic and/or numeric code for the administrative division of the
> country concerned (state, province, department, etc.), as included in
> International Standard ISO 3166-2/1998 and when deemed desirable to
> enhance the use of the code, or when requested by the country
> concerned.

You can find three letter administrative divisions for UK at https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:GB. There you will see that `HAO`, which has `HNS` in SubDiv column, is in Hunslow (London borough) and `HWX`, which has `LND` in SubDiv column, is in City of London.

As for coordinates, `5126N 00024W` means `51.26` longitude and `0.24` latitude.

Comment: If I search for `HAO` or `HWX` in https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:GB, nothing is captured.

Comment: See modified answer. You have to search for value that is in `SubDiv` column, which is `HNS` for `HAO` and `LND` for `HWX`.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that that means that the town I'm actually looking for — https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Hanworth,+Norwich/@52.8724825,1.2494028,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x47d75cae1237c9a1:0xafeb0d2650b60ec6!8m2!3d52.8724959!4d1.2581449!16s%2Fg%2F1jkyh3phj?entry=ttu — isn't even registered with UN/LOCODE.

Comment: No, it seems it's not registered. The closest registered is Aldborough: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Aldborough,+Norwich+NR11+7AA,+Zdru%C5%BEeno+kraljestvo/@52.8627886,1.2211825,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x47d75d310f10b6df:0x78595cb14b17f5dd!8m2!3d52.862765!4d1.241825!16s%2Fg%2F11bc5v3md5?entry=ttu